# IBluetoothGatt.java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

I am trying to create a Bluetooth application in Android Studio.  I am using BluetoothGatt.java which requires IBluetoothGatt.java which is not in the sources folder in my android studio install.

I downloaded IBluetoothGatt.java from grepcode and saved it in the sources folder (where BluetoothGatt.java is located) but when I try to import IBluetooth.java it can't find it.

Is there a step I'm missing?  I've never done anything like this before so I'm not familiar with how to import a downloaded file into my project.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need the source? It's a generated file and it should be in the binary.

Comment: Again, I'm not totally familiar with this process but there is no reason I need the source.  A function in BluetoothGatt.java uses an IBluetoothGatt object and it is highlighted in red because it cannot find IBluetoothGatt.java and I can't import it.  Are you saying I can ignore this error?  The code compiles fine as is.